# Sticky element not scrolling inside scrollable element when overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have structure like this, I have fixed header and content is scrollable in which there will be infinite scrolling. I have one div in right which should be sticky always and the content should scroll.

Everything's working fine and I've achieved that. The only challenge is when the sticky div content height is more than the viewport in that case it should scroll a bit till it's visible completely in the viewport and it should be sticky.

CodeSandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-overflow-0pkqip?file=/index.html

How can I achieve this? Any suggestion?

Here is my code:

```css
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    #header {
      align-items: flex-start;
      padding: 16px 24px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 3;
      height: 167px;
      background-color: brown;
      color: #fff;
    }
    
    #render-view {
      color: #606369;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      position: relative;
      overflow: scroll;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      min-height: calc(100vh - 226px + 0px);
      max-height: calc(100vh - 226px + 0px);
    }
    
    #content {
      display: flex;
      padding: 0px 24px !important;
      gap: 24px;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    #main-content {
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 1096px;
      background-color: cadetblue;
      height: 200vh;
    }
    
    #right-content {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 16px 24px;
      min-width: 325px;
      width: 325px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      z-index: 8;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin-top: 24px;
      margin-bottom: 16px;
      position: sticky;
      top: 24px;
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
    }
    
    .list-item {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      </head>
    
      <body>
        <div id="app">
          <div id="header">
            Header
          </div>
          <div id="render-view">
            <div id="content">
              <div id="main-content">
                <h1>Main Content</h1>
                <h4>
                  This is an Infinite Scrolling Component based on the content.
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div>
                <div id="right-content">
                  <h1>Right Content</h1>
                  <p>
                    This card should be sticky, but for small screens content is
                    overflowing and it should scroll a bit only till it's completely
                    visible. But it's scrolling when it reaches to end.
                  </p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 1</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 2</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 3</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 4</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 5</p>
                  <p class="list-item">There is still more content</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 7</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 8</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 9</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 10</p>
                  <p class="list-item">List Item 11</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="src/index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your code a bit.
Basically you want to make both your `main-content` and your `right-content` sticky.

See my updated example: https://codesandbox.io/s/sticky-overflow-forked-tccwll

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't helps, as the right content is not sticky anymore it's scrolling when left content is scrolling. It should be sticky but can scroll only when it's content is overflowing.

Comment: I see what you mean. My bad. I've updated my example. Does it work like you want now?